# How to define an exponent as the index position of a string

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, char, int

I am trying to make an int method that converts a binary number into a base 10 number. I think my loop is structured correctly, but I cant figure out how to relate index position to an exponent. Basically if there is a '1' in the string, i want to return it as 2 to the power of whatever the index position of that char is. Also, this would require me to inverse the index (so that the 0 position is the rightmost char of the string. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static int BinaryToNumber(String numberInput)
{
    int len = numberInput.length();

    for(int i=len-1; i<len; i--)
    {
        if(i == '1');
        {
            return n;
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Read up on the `<<` operator. Or initialize n as 1, and multiply it by 2 each time through the loop.

Comment: Why not [`Integer.parseInt(numberInput, 2);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the Java built-in routines when possible - as I said in my comment [`Integer.parseInt(numberInput, 2);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). By convention, Java method names begin with a lower case letter. Finally, you can fix your code (and I added a small test harness) with something like,

```
public static int binaryToNumber(String numberInput) {
    if (numberInput == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int ret = 0;
    char[] ni = numberInput.trim().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < ni.length; i++) {
        if (ni[i] == '1') {
            // This is 2 ^ (n) where (n) is based on the position from the right.
            ret += 1 << ni.length - i - 1;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String t = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        System.out.printf("%s = %d%n", t, binaryToNumber(t));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my implementation for the problem

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "100101";
    System.out.println(toDecimal(str));
}

private static int toDecimal(String binary) {
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
        int a = (int) binary.charAt(i) - 48;
        double secondPart = 1 << (binary.length()-1) - i;
        result +=  a * secondPart;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I hope that helps
Salam